# Mysql GRANT Statement formatting

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to Grant privileges to a wordpress user but keep getting errors no matter how I format it.
This is the statement:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,ALTER
ON wordpress.*
TO wordpress@localhost
IDENTIFIED BY 'thepassword';
```

I keep getting MySQL

> error 1065 "you have an error in your sql syntax near 'thepassword';

I have tried ` and ' and reformatting the statment as one line and multipul lines and keep getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it was removed in mysql 8.0 see [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)

Use instead

```
CREATE USER 'wordpress'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by 'password!';
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,ALTER ON wordpress.* TO 'wordpress'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 0):

`IDENTIFIED BY` belongs to `CREATE USER` and not to `GRANT`.

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,ALTER
ON wordpress.*
TO 'wordpress'@'localhost';
```

should do the trick. Assuming the user already exists. If not you have to create him with

```
CREATE USER 'wordpress'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'thepassword';
```